# Compare macro value with dataset and goto next level

Tags: macros, sas

I am having a dataset which one variable is date. I passed some value to macro variable '**frodate**'. Now i want if value is exist in dataset variable date then goto to a label.
but my program does not perform match. It is show condition is false,but value is in the dataset. Please help to do the same.

```
DATA _NULL_ ;
SET STOCK.NIFTY_IDX;
%IF &FRODATE = DATE %THEN %GOTO NEXT ;
RUN;
```

I don't understand what mistake i am doing. I know this is a very small problem, but i can't understand the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing macro language (`%if`) with sas program syntax (`if`). SAS Macro language is used to write sas programs - and so all macro statements are essentially resolved BEFORE the sas program runs.  Data steps cannot (easily) drive macro logic, *during* that data step.

Also, macro language statements (such as %if) must be wrapped in a macro (`%macro x; %mend;`), which I assume is the case if you are successfully resolving FALSE.  This is expected, unless your "&FRODATE" macro variable actually contains the character string "DATE"  (macro only works with text, and it cannot *easily* read dataset variables).

Anyway, my interpretation of your question leads me to think that you need logic as follows:

```
/* create a sas macro as we are using macro logic */
%macro some_macro(frodate);

/* first run datastep and convert the dataset variable into a macro variable */
data _null_;
set stock.nifty_idx;
call symputx('Nifty_dt',date); 
stop;
run;

/* the above is parsed and the macro processor receives a value for NIFTY_DT */

%if &frodate=&nifty_dt %then %goto next; /* if a match, go to the "label" */
%else %return; /* else exit the macro or some other logic */

%next:  /* this is the "label", note the colon - not a semicolon */
%put success!;
%mend;

/* now RUN the macro to execute the logic.. */
%some_macro;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand my error and resolved the same. I do it in different manner.

```
%LET TEMDATE=%SYSFUNC(PUTN(&FDATE,DATE9.));
proc sql noprint;
select left(put(count(*),8.)) into :EXIST
from STOCK.NIFTY_&IDXFUT
where date = "&TEMDATE"d;
quit;

%IF &EXIST = 0 %THEN %DO......
```

Thanks for your valuable answer..